# crash of tikz-uml and pgf-umlcd

Tags: pgf-umlcd

I am stuck with inheritance diagram using `pgf-umlcd`. I am using both `pgf-umlcd` and `tikz-uml`. There is no error but the inherited line is not showing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{abstractclass}[text width=5cm]{Shape}{0,0}
  \end{abstractclass}

  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Rectangle}{-3,-3}
    \inherit{Shape}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Ellipse}{3,-3}
    \inherit{Shape}
  \end{class}
  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Circle}{3,-6}
    \inherit{Ellipse}
  \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date distribution?

Comment: Dear harish i am using up-to date one. problem is that if i interchange the packages then one of them is not working correctly

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains things fully:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \umlnote already defined.
>                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
> ```

Both packages attempt to define the command `\umlnote`. *There can only be one!* – Highlander

You can work around this by choosing which package should maintain normal functionality of `\umlnote` and loading that one last. Then, between loading the two packages, use something like

```
\let\umlnoteold\umlnote
\let\umlnote\relax
```

The first line is optional, and is used to store the first package's version of `\umlnote` for later use if needed. This might involve patching the first package to use this saved command instead of the original `\umlnote`. The second line "erases" the definition of `\umlnote` so that when the second package tries to create the command, `\newcommand` doesn't throw an error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\let\umlnotetikzuml\umlnote
\let\umlnote\relax
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{abstractclass}[text width=5cm]{Shape}{0,0}
  \end{abstractclass}

  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Rectangle}{-3,-3}
    \inherit{Shape}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Ellipse}{3,-3}
    \inherit{Shape}
  \end{class}
  \begin{class}[text width=4cm]{Circle}{3,-6}
    \inherit{Ellipse}
  \end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]